# What tool produces this type of layout?

Tags: power, integrated-circuit, layout, vlsi, cadence

I don't under this layout figure (5.c) in pic attached.
This is a screenshot from research paper in this link:-

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=7573442

Alternate link for the paper in case if you are not a member of IEEE
https://1drv.ms/b/s!AuHq5DWFZ2WugWlDfRyx1OofH1-N

[image]

My basic Curiosity is that layout are generally in shape of squares and rectangles, but in this layout what is that blot (ink drop) like thing in fig 5.c

Comment: As the article is about power, my guess is that it is some "power in this area" graph. Second guess: purple and yellow are separately powered blocks.

Comment: @Oldfart Sir, I am doing a project in this paper.can you tell me how can I achieve this layout like which software i need to use to obtain this type of  layout.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you. Layout and the related tools where driven by other experts in the  companies I worked for. I would also suggest you change your question more along the lines of: "what tool produces this type of layout?".

Comment: @Oldfart  Thanks for suggestion

Comment: I am not registered at IEEE.... perhaps if you have access to a link for the original publication outside IEEE would help.

Comment: @Brethlosze here is a link,you can download the pdf of the paper.Please help me with this. https://1drv.ms/b/s!AuHq5DWFZ2WugWlDfRyx1OofH1-N

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because although the subject matter is of an electrical nature the basic question is not.

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry sir

Answer (score 3):

The "blob" in the picture is a depiction of an ASIC physical layout created by a place-and-route algorithm. These algorithms often use randomized simulating annealing methods to place logic within a grid. These methods don't inherently favor a rectilinear layout; they often create layouts with an organic, cloud-like appearance. Similar algorithms are used for FPGA design as well.

These sorts of layouts are not uncommon in larger modern digital designs, like microcontrollers or SoCs. A few examples can be seen in die shots, including:

- [This ATTiny4 on Zeptobars](https://zeptobars.com/en/read/atmel-tiny4-attiny4-microcontroller). Manually laid-out blocks can be seen in the top left and bottom, probably for analog functionality and flash memory.
- [This PIC24, also on Zeptobars](https://zeptobars.com/en/read/PIC24EP32GP202-PIC24-microcontroller-opamp-adc). Similarly, there are a couple more regular regions which probably contain flash memory, SRAM, and/or analog components.
- [The Apple A12 Bionic SoC on Anandtech](https://www.anandtech.com/show/13393/techinsights-publishes-apple-a12-die-shot-our-take). Interestingly, this layout is composed of many different regions of automated layout, with regular rectangular blocks of what is probably SRAM positioned throughout the die.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a power integrity tool in a VLSI back-end flow, likely Cadence Voltus or similar.